# Generating an mp3/wav/ogg Waveform using Java

Tags: java, audio, waveform

Like soundcloud and zippyshare<sup>1</sup>, how can I generate an audio waveform image using java?  are there any frameworks or open source libraries available for such case?

I wanted to generate an audio waveform as an image, and upon loading a track, the waveform image with will be loaded.

1. [image]

Comment: *"Like soundcloud and zippyshare,"*  A picture paints a thousand words.  Show some examples of this.

Comment: Please look at this link : http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Build-an-Audio-Waveform-Display/

Comment: Like I edited into the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Program that create a PNG waveform for an audio file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017283/java-program-that-create-a-png-waveform-for-an-audio-file)

Comment: there are dozens of such questions on SO, I chose the one that has a complete solution

Comment: @DenisTulskiy Where's the one who has a complete solution?

Answer (score 1):

Start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12121808/418556).  The "further processing.." in this case might be to add each instantaneous value to a `GeneralPath`, then (scale that path to fit within the painting area and) draw it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two questions with answers on SO:

[Java Program to create a PNG waveform for an audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017283/java-program-that-create-a-png-waveform-for-an-audio-file)

[How can I draw sound data from my wav file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879210/how-can-i-draw-sound-data-from-my-wav-file)

I like my answer to the second question the best because it explains how to do it in all cases, but it doesn't give code.

There are lots of other answers, too.