# Android - create waveform of the audio file (OGG)

Tags: java, android, audio, ogg

How can I create a simple waveform of the ogg file (like in [RingDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ringdroid))? Is there any simple way?

I found a source code of RingDroid (https://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/) but it´s not support ogg format. I´m using Android 4.0+.

Is there some easy way to do it?

Thanks for advice.

EDIT: I want create something like this (waveform for the whole song)

[image]

I hope, it´s clear. If you have some questions, please ask.

Comment: Start with this [answer][1] ,you will be using java sound API .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120399/how-to-get-pcm-data-from-a-wav-file/12121808#12121808

Comment: But I can´t use Java sound API (AudioInputStream, ...) in Android.

Comment: Why it´s "on hold"? What should I add or edit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Visualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) to get the waveform data

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
.
.
.
int audioSessionID = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();

// Enable Equalizer if waveform was affected by device volume.
// Equalizer equalizer = new Equalizer(0, audioSessionID);
// equalizer.setEnabled(true);

// Need android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO.
Visualizer visualizer = new Visualizer(audioSessionID);
visualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
visualizer.setDataCaptureListener(new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
            public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                    int samplingRate) {
                // Send bytes (waveform) to your custom UI view to show it.
            }

            public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {}
        }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);
visualizer.setEnabled(true);

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                visualizer.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

// TODO :: Do not forget to release visualizer onPause.
```

Check this view http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4.4_r1/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.java#VisualizerView on how to draw the waveform from the data retrieved from the Visualizer

```
if (mPoints == null || mPoints.length < mBytes.length * 4) {
    mPoints = new float[mBytes.length * 4];
}

mRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

for (int i = 0; i < mBytes.length - 1; i++) {
    mPoints[i * 4] = mRect.width() * i / (mBytes.length - 1);
    mPoints[i * 4 + 1] = mRect.height() / 2
            + ((byte) (mBytes[i] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
    mPoints[i * 4 + 2] = mRect.width() * (i + 1) / (mBytes.length - 1);
    mPoints[i * 4 + 3] = mRect.height() / 2
            + ((byte) (mBytes[i + 1] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
}

canvas.drawLines(mPoints, mForePaint);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I´m using something like this now and it´s create a waveform of the current playing part of the song, but not the waveform of the whole song. Do you understand me? Do you know how to change it, to create waveform for the whole song?

Comment: @PepaZapletal have you found anything realted to it ?