# Is It Possible To Use The android.media.audiofx.Visualizer Without Requiring Sound File To Play?

Tags: java, android, audio, visualization, waveform

the android.media.audiofx.Visualizer class has an method

```
public int getWaveForm (byte[] waveform)
```

that returns x,y coordinates for visualizing the waveform of an audioSession:

```
public Visualizer (int audioSession)
```

Is it possible to use the Visualizer without requiring a sound file to play?

If not, is there an equivalent library that does this?:

```
 public int getWaveForm (byte[] waveform)
```

note: the following answer is not right even though it is marked CLOSED - [Android - create waveform of the audio file (OGG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913667/android-create-waveform-of-the-audio-file-ogg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `Visualizer(0)`, it will use the output mix.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html

Comment: Some Android versions disabled the visualizer(0) option... I wish you lucky!